# Interference of invisible IR and UV lasers is visible?

Tags: interference

By the formula : $$\cos a+\cos b=2\cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)$$

We could think the crossing of IR and UV could be made in the visible spectrum ?

Is this used in some 3D displays technology ?

Comment: Do you know frequency mixing in non-linear optics? Second-harmonic generation and four-wave mixing are a rather common method.

Comment: Is this used in 3D display, but a display in space we could go in ? I thought we could use the average frequency could correspond to an energy level of some atoms in a non toxic gas ?